# Maximum product C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, max

I am given a few array of both negative and positive numbers.
I should Find the maximum product obtained from multiplying 2 adjacent numbers in the array.
This is the code I wrote :

```
 #include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int adjacentElementsProduct(vector<int> inputArray) 
  {
      for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); i++) {
      if((inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1])>(inputArray[i+1] * inputArray[i+2])) {
        std::cout << inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1] << "\n";
       }  else  if((inputArray[i+1] * inputArray[i+2])>(inputArray[i+2] * inputArray[i+3])) {
           std::cout << inputArray[i+1] * inputArray[i+2] << "\n";
           } else if((inputArray[i+2] * inputArray[i+3])>(inputArray[i+3] * inputArray[i+4])) {
               std::cout << inputArray[i+2] * inputArray[i+3] << "\n";
               } else if((inputArray[i+3] * inputArray[i+4])>(inputArray[i+4] * inputArray[i+5])) {
                   std::cout << inputArray[i+3] * inputArray[i+4] << "\n";
                   } else {
           std::cout << "Unknow" << "\n";
       } return 1;
      }
  }

int main() {
  adjacentElementsProduct({5, 8});
  adjacentElementsProduct({1,2,3});
  adjacentElementsProduct({1,5,10,9});
  adjacentElementsProduct({5,1,2,3,1,4});
  adjacentElementsProduct({4,12,3,1,5});
  adjacentElementsProduct({3,6,-2,-5,7,3});
  adjacentElementsProduct({9, 5, 10, 2, 24, -1, -48});
  adjacentElementsProduct({5, 6, -4, 2, 3, 2, -23});
  adjacentElementsProduct({-23, 4, -5, 99, -27, 329, -2, 7, -921});
  adjacentElementsProduct({1,0,1,0,1000});
  adjacentElementsProduct({1,2,3,0});
  return 1 ;
}
```

Output:

```
40
6
90
5
48
18
50
30
-20
Unknow
6
```

The code only compares the product of inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1] and inputArray[i+1] * inputArray[i+2] But I want to find the maximum product among all the numbers in array.

Comment: I have not understood.  So do you need to find the maximum product of adjacent elements or of all elements?

Comment: I need to find the maximum product of all adjacent elements in the array.

Comment: @PooryaKeshavarzi -- What if the vector had 1000 elements?  I'm sure you don't want to write 2000 lines of code.

Comment: Your code exhibits undefined behavior. Your loop will allow `i` to reach `inputArray.size()-1`, at which point `inputArray[i+1]` is an out-of-bounds array access. You wrote a loop, so use it. *(Also, please consider saner indentation. Usually an `else` gets the same indentation level as the corresponding `if`.)*

Answer (score 1):

You want to loop over the input vector and compute the products of adjacent elements.
Then, you want to find the maximum of those products. You don't need all that hardcoded `[i+1], [i+2], [i+3], ...` shenanigans, you already have something that can get all those numbers for you -- a for loop.

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(vector<int> inputArray) 
{
      // Set initial max product to a very small number so that 
      // it is always replaced by our first product
      int maxProduct = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
      for(int i = 0; 
            i < inputArray.size() - 1;  /* because we will be doing i + 1 inside the loop */
            i++) {
          // Calculate product of this and next element
          int product = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1];
          
          if (product > maxProduct) 
              maxProduct = product; // This product is the greatest so far,  
                                    // so keep it and get rid of the old max.
      }
      return maxProduct;
}
```

To explain how this works, let's look at the execution of the function for an example input. Let's say we do `adjacentElementsProduct({5,1,2,3,1,4});`

1. `maxProduct` is set to some very large negative number (let's say -99999999)
2. `inputArray.size()` is 6. `inputArray.size() - 1` is 5.
3. `i = 0`. Is `0 < 5`? Yes. Go inside loop

   1. `product = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1] = 5`
   2. is `5 > maxProduct (-99999999)`? Yes. Set `maxProduct = 5`
   3. Increment `i` to 1.
4. `i = 1`. Is `1 < 5`? Yes. Go inside loop

   1. `product = inputArray[1] * inputArray[2] = 2`
   2. is `2 > maxProduct (5)`? No.
   3. Increment `i` to 2.
5. `i = 2`. Is `2 < 5`? Yes. Go inside loop

   1. `product = inputArray[2] * inputArray[3] = 6`
   2. is `6 > maxProduct (5)`? Yes. Set `maxProduct = 6`
   3. Increment `i` to 3.
6. `i = 3`. Is `3 < 5`? Yes. Go inside loop

   1. `product = inputArray[3] * inputArray[4] = 3`
   2. is `3 > maxProduct (6)`? No.
   3. Increment `i` to 4.
7. `i = 4`. Is `4 < 5`? Yes. Go inside loop

   1. `product = inputArray[4] * inputArray[5] = 4`
   2. is `4 > maxProduct (6)`? No.
   3. Increment `i` to 5.
8. `i = 5`. Is `5 < 5`? No.
9. Return `maxProduct`, which is 6.

Comment: `int maxProduct = -9999999;` -- `int maxProduct = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks! -999999 was a placeholder until I looked at the docs for what `numeric_limits` was called!

Comment: Hey.Thanks.Can U explaine Ur if part?

Comment: `if (product > maxProduct)` will only be entered if the product of the current two items is greater than the max product we've encountered so far, i.e. the current product _is the new maximum_, so we write its value to the `maxProduct` variable @PooryaKeshavarzi

Comment: You might also wanna change `for(int i = 0; ...)` to `for(size_t i = 0; ...)` to squash signed/unsigned comparison complaints.

Comment: @NathanPierson I'm just using the loop that was already in OP's question. I figured adding more things to the answer would unnecessarily confuse OP.

Comment: Hi.I`m new to Coding then I am confused a little now .Can U explaine the solution a little bit more?I just did not completly get it

Comment: @PooryaKeshavarzi I've added a step-by-step explanation to my answer.

Comment: I have done what U have said but I am receiving this error : error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
       int maxProduct = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
                        ^~~
main.cpp:6:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
       int maxProduct = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
                                            ^~~

Comment: It only needs to be a very large negative number (e.g. `int maxProduct = -999999999`) so that the product of the first two elements overwrites it. Alternatively, do `int maxProduct = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1]` so that it starts out as the product of the first two elements.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked But I need U to explain me something.Do U have any socials like WhatsApp or skype or instagram?Just to be in touch

Answer (score 0):

I think your function is overkill.  You can do this with a *running* maxima:

```
const unsigned int length = inputArray.length();
int maximum = inputArray[0] * inputArray[1];
for (unsigned int i = 1U; i < (length - 1U); ++i)
{
    const int product = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i + 1];
    if (product > maximum) maximum = product;
}
```

This can be further optimized but that is an exercise for the OP.

**Edit 1:  Via Pointers**
This may be more optimal, but only assembly language will tell (or profiling):

```
const unsigned int length = inputArray.length();
int const * p_first = &inputArray[0];
int const * p_second = &inputArray[1];
int maximum = (*p_first++) * (*p_second++);
for (unsigned int i = 1u; i < (length - 1); ++i)
{
    int product = (*p_first++) * (*p_second++);
    if (product > maximum) maximum = product;
}
```

In the above code fragment, the two array locations are maintained in pointers.  The pointers can be maintained in registers.  No need to calculate the offset within the loop each time.  Incrementing pointers is simple and quick operation.  Some processors have instructions that can dereference a pointer and increment in a single instruction.  Some compilers may perform this optimization depending on the optimization setting.

**Edit 2: Tracking Previous Value**
Another optimization is to reduce the memory accesses by about half, by remembering the previous value in the array:

```
const unsigned int length = inputArray.length();
int previous = inputArray[0];
int next     = inputArray[1];
int maximum  = previous * next;
previous = next;
for (unsigned int i = 1u; i < length; ++i)
{
    next = inputArray[i];
    const int product = previous * next;
    if (product > maximum) maximum = product;
    previous = next;
}
```

In the above code fragment, the previous array value is remembered in a variable.  This eliminates the need to access the array for the previous value; only one array access is required.

The compiler *may* perform this optimization at higher optimization levels.  The proof is to compare the assembly language of the variables fragments.

Answer (score 0):

There's an algorithm in `<numeric>` that does this for you:

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(std::vector<int> const & inputArray) 
{
  // [[assert: inputArray.size > 1 ]]

  return std::inner_product(inputArray.begin(), inputArray.end() - 1,
                            inputArray.begin() + 1, 
                            0, 
                            [](int i, int j) { return std::max(i, j); }, 
                            std::multiplies{});
}
```

which is about as efficient, and readable as it gets.

Comment: Thanks for Ur help But I am far way newer to coding So I do it with simpler things.Thanks anyway

Comment: @PooryaKeshavarzi Ok, that's up to you. IMO, this solution is easier to understand than using raw loops though.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function should not output any message. It is the caller of the function will decide whether to output a message or not.

The function should return an iterator or a pair of iterators that point to the two adjacent elements with the maximum product.

As for your function implementation then it has undefined behavior because it can access non-existent elements of the vector.

I can suggest the following function definition as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::pair<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator>
adjacentElementsProduct( const std::vector<int> &v )
{
    std::pair<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator> 
    p = { std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) };

    if (not ( v.size() < 2 ))
    {
        p.second = std::next( std::begin( v ) );
        long long int max_product = static_cast<long long int>( *p.first ) * *p.second;

        for (auto prev = p.second, current = std::next( p.second );
            current != std::end( v );
            std::advance( prev, 1 ), std::advance( current, 1 ))
        {
            if (max_product < static_cast<long long int>( *prev ) * *current)
            {
                p = { prev, current };
            }
        }
    }

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 5, 8 };
    auto p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { 1,2,3 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { 1,5,10,9 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { 5,1,2,3,1,4 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { 4,12,3,1,5 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { 3,6,-2,-5,7,3 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { 9, 5, 10, 2, 24, -1, -48 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { 5, 6, -4, 2, 3, 2, -23 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { -23, 4, -5, 99, -27, 329, -2, 7, -921 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1000 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';

    v = { 1,2,3,0 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( *p.first ) * *p.second << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
40
6
90
6
48
21
48
30
-14
0
6
```

If you do not know yet iterators than the function can be defined the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

std::pair<std::vector<int>::size_type, std::vector<int>::size_type>
adjacentElementsProduct( const std::vector<int> &v )
{
    std::pair<std::vector<int>::size_type, std::vector<int>::size_type>
    p = { 0, v.size() };

    if (not ( v.size() < 2 ))
    {
        p.second = 1;
        long long int max_product = static_cast<long long int>( p.first ) * p.second;

        for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 3; i < v.size(); i++ )
        {
            if (max_product < static_cast<long long int>( v[i - 1] ) * v[i] )
            {
                p = { i - 1, i };
            }
        }
    }

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 5, 8 };
    auto p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { 1,2,3 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { 1,5,10,9 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { 5,1,2,3,1,4 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { 4,12,3,1,5 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { 3,6,-2,-5,7,3 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { 9, 5, 10, 2, 24, -1, -48 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { 5, 6, -4, 2, 3, 2, -23 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { -23, 4, -5, 99, -27, 329, -2, 7, -921 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1000 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';

    v = { 1,2,3,0 };
    p = adjacentElementsProduct( v );
    std::cout << static_cast< long long int >( p.first ) * p.second << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But I don`t understand Ur code for now cause I am really new But Thanks anyway I have just made it myself

Comment: @PooryaKeshavarzi See my updated post. As for your solution then I am sure it is wrong.:)